# Reload Camel.xml without restarting ActiveMQ

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-camel

Is it posible to reload camel configuration for ActiveMQ without restarting service?

Comment: Or there are any alternatives to this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you by reloading mean re-read the xml configuration camel.xml (or similar) within a standalone ActiveMQ installation, then it's non trivial. ActiveMQ is merly a spring application that creates some beans on startup (ActiveMQ, Jetty, Camel..).

What you need is a more dynamic runtime. [Apache Karaf](http://karaf.apache.org/) can easily run ActiveMQ as well as Camel context files that redeploy upon change. You might want to look into [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org/) and [RedHat Jboss Fuse](http://www.jboss.org/products/fuse) which are prebundled packages with Karaf+Camel+ActiveMQ. It's trivial to setup from a plain Karaf though.

[How to install Camel in Karaf](http://camel.apache.org/karaf)

[A tutorial](http://www.liquid-reality.de/display/liquid/2012/01/03/Karaf+Tutorial+Part+5+-+Running+Apache+Camel+integrations+in+OSGi) by [Christian Schneider](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930728/christian-schneider)